# How to authorize one method differently than the controller? (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On a project I am currently working on I have three roles: Admin, Super-user and User.

Admins can delete users, delete comments etc, but Super-users must be able to delete comments too. So I built an `AdminController` and Authorized it with Admin. One method must be accessable with the Super-user, so I authorized it for the Super-user but that won't work.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    (... here be only admin methods ...)

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Super-user")]
    public ActionResult Delete()
    {
        //deletes a comment
        return View();
    }

    (... here be only admin methods ...)
}
```

I looked into overriding the `Authorize` attribute but I'm trying to find a solution where that is not needed, any idea's on how to authorize just one method for the Super-user?

The Admin as the Super-user must have access to the method `Delete()`.

Thanks!

Comment: It should works with your code.

Comment: So the user should have roles `Admin` and `Super-user`?  That should work.

Comment: You should authorize both in the controller level [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super-user")]

Comment: @Felix Cen: But I have more methods in the controller, I don't want the Super-user to have acces to these other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as @Felix Cen pointed specifying this should work at controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super-user")]
```

and then specify this at the method level

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Super-user")]
```

Alternatively you can use a deny attribute as pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682545/deny-custom-role) question

```
public class DenyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        if (httpContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            return false;
        }

        if (Users.Length > 0 && Users.Split(',').Any( u => string.Compare( u.Trim(), user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) {
            return false;
        }

        if (Roles.Length > 0 && Roles.Split(',').Any( u => user.IsInRole(u.Trim()))) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Another question here(i think that i sort of like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746998/override-authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc) specific answer here)

> My personal take on this would be to split the controller. Just create
>   another controller For the actions you don't need authentication.
>
> Or you could have :
>
> ```
> BaseController
> doesn't require authentication - here you have all your "base stuff" :).
>
> BaseAuthController : BaseController
> all actions here require authentication.
> ```
>
> That way you can have authentication when you want , just by deriving
>   from a specific class.